# Connect-AzAccount Not Popping Up Interactive Prompt

Tags: c#, azure, powershell

Using System.Management.Automation within a C# Windows form project. I have a method that should create an Azure SQL managed instance via PowerShell. If I run the same PowerShell script manually through a PS command prompt it works fine. But when invoked through the C# project it errors out. Specifically the errors come back as:

***Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Azure.Identity.AuthenticationRecord> Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential.AuthenticateAsync(Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.***

***Run Connect-AzAccount to login.***

Below is the C# method I have created. And below that is the first portion of that PS1 script that is erroring out. Any suggestions? I have ensured that AzureRM isn't present on the PC, have ensured that Edge is the default browser (for the interactive pop-up), and run the executable as Administrator.

```html
        public bool CreateAzSqlManagedInstance()
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            PropertyInfo execPolProp = iss.GetType().GetProperty(@"ExecutionPolicy");
            if (execPolProp != null && execPolProp.CanWrite)
            {
                execPolProp.SetValue(iss, ExecutionPolicy.Bypass, null);
            }

            var success = true;
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);
            var commandStr = "";
            commandStr += string.Format("$NSnetworkModels = \"{0}\"\r\n", "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models");
            commandStr += string.Format("$NScollections = \"{0}\"\r\n", "System.Collections.Generic");
            commandStr += string.Format("$SubscriptionId = \"{0}\"\r\n", SubscriptionId);
            commandStr += string.Format("$resourceGroupName = \"{0}\"\r\n", ResourceGroupName);
            commandStr += string.Format("$location = \"{0}\"\r\n", "eastus2");
            commandStr += string.Format("$vNetName = \"{0}\"\r\n", VNetName);
            commandStr += string.Format("$vNetAddressPrefix = \"{0}\"\r\n", "10.0.0.0/16");
            commandStr += string.Format("$miSubnetName = \"{0}\"\r\n", MiSubnetName);
            commandStr += string.Format("$miSubnetAddressPrefix = \"{0}\"\r\n", "10.0.0.0/24");
            commandStr += string.Format("$instanceName = \"{0}\"\r\n", MiName);
            commandStr += string.Format("$miAdminSqlLogin = \"{0}\"\r\n", AzureSqlLogin);
            commandStr += string.Format("$miAdminSqlPassword = \"{0}\"\r\n", AzureSqlPassword);
            commandStr += string.Format("$edition = \"{0}\"\r\n", "General Purpose");
            commandStr += string.Format("$vCores = {0}\r\n", 4);
            commandStr += string.Format("$maxStorage = {0}\r\n", 128);
            commandStr += string.Format("$computeGeneration = \"{0}\"\r\n", "Gen5");
            commandStr += string.Format("$license = \"{0}\"\r\n", "LicenseIncluded");
            commandStr += File.ReadAllText(@".\CreateManagedInstance.ps1");
            ps.AddScript(commandStr);            
            var InvokeResult = ps.Invoke();
            if (ps.HadErrors)
            {
                success = false;
                foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error)
                {
                    log.ErrorFormat("Exception: {0}", error.Exception.Message);
                }
            }
            return success;
        }
```

```html
# Ensure the proper modules are present
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'AzureRM*'} | Uninstall-Module
Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force -AllowClobber
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

# Connect to Azure
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount 

# Set subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId 
...
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the winform with elevated permissions?

Comment: As mentioned above, I have tried running the executable as Administrator. But this didn't make any difference in the outcome. Aside from that, I'm not sure how to assign elevated permissions to the Form itself or the method that's being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft bundles instances of AzureRM (a previous version of the PowerShell Azure management library) with Visual Studio. At least in my case with VS 2019. Once I ensured that all instances of AzureRM were removed then my C# method that invokes the newer Az PowerShell Azure management library completed successfully.(1)

(1) - by "completed successfully" I mean that if you wait for literally hours for the synchronous operation to complete. A new Azure SQL managed instance being created as part of a new virtual cluster is a verrrrry long-tailed operation. :-/